# Center text value of a field in polygon and display

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, labeling

I would like to display the value of a field over the polygon.

In this case, the field name is Subname,
and i would like to use a specific font.

Would like to perform this action for each polygon on the layer.

Comment: You simply need to turn on labelling for the layer. Go to the label tab in the layer properties.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest as well. I can't believe this has not been asked before. If that isn't it, then the question should be clarified.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9459/8104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific instructions then would be to right-click the layer in the table of contents and go to "Properties". Then choose the "Labels" tab. Check the box to "Label Features in this layer" and choose your "Subname" field as your "Label Field". Change the Font using the options under "Text Symbol".